# Python 2,3 Convert Integer to "bytes" Cleanly

Tags: python

The shortest ways I have found are:

```
n = 5

# Python 2.
s = str(n)
i = int(s)

# Python 3.
s = bytes(str(n), "ascii")
i = int(s)
```

I am particularly concerned with two factors: readability and portability.  The second method, for Python 3, is ugly.  However, I think it may be backwards compatible.

Is there a shorter, cleaner way that I have missed?  I currently make a lambda expression to fix it with a new function, but maybe that's unnecessary.

Comment: `bytes(str(n),"ascii")` is not backwards compatible, `bytes()` was introduced in python 3.x only.

Comment: I realize that you are trying to be broad to keep it from being to specific, but it's hard to tell why you're trying to do this or what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, I tried it at http://www.trypython.org/#, because my current Python is 3.3, but I acknowledge that that's hardly conclusive.

Comment: When `bytes` exists in 2, it's only an alias for `str`.  `bytearray` exists, though, and has a `bytearray(string, encoding[, errors]) -> bytearray` call signature.

Comment: @TylerCrompton, I first ran into it while porting some of my earlier code that builds packets for a custom networking layer--so it does need to use bytearrays.  It was something I wasn't clear on, so I generalized it into a question.

Comment: I don't think you have a choice in Python 3 but to use a two-step conversion, since strings and bytes are different types. But you can leave the encoding parameter off as the default will always be sufficient.

Comment: I take it back, it appears the default for the encoding parameter is a recent addition - it doesn't work at ideone.com which uses Python 3.1.2.

Comment: Why do you want the text representation? Don't networks usually use raw bytes?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: exactly.  It seems awkward to convert to unicode and then _back_ into a raw bytes object.

Comment: I think what @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams meant was that a network protocol would be more likely to want binary `0x05` rather than ASCII `'5'`, but I know there are plenty of protocols that are text based. As for the double conversion to Unicode then raw bytes, it's eminently sensible when you've experienced the alternative. In Python 2 it's far too easy to get confused about whether you have a string of characters or a string of bytes and it leads to no end of bugs.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

To convert a string to a sequence of bytes in either Python 2 or Python 3, you use the string's `encode` method. If you don't supply an encoding parameter `'ascii'` is used, which will always be good enough for numeric digits.

```
s = str(n).encode()
```

- Python 2: http://ideone.com/Y05zVY
- Python 3: http://ideone.com/XqFyOj

In Python 2 `str(n)` already produces bytes; the `encode` will do a double conversion as this string is implicitly converted to Unicode and back again to bytes. It's unnecessary work, but it's harmless and is completely compatible with Python 3.

---

**Answer 2:**

Above is the answer to the question that was actually asked, which was to produce a string of ASCII bytes in human-readable form. But since people keep coming here trying to get the answer to a *different* question, I'll answer that question too. If you want to convert `10` to `b'10'` use the answer above, but if you want to convert `10` to `b'\x0a\x00\x00\x00'` then keep reading.

The [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) was specifically provided for converting between various types and their binary representation as a sequence of bytes. The conversion from a type to bytes is done with [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack). There's a format parameter `fmt` that determines which conversion it should perform. For a 4-byte integer, that would be `i` for signed numbers or `I` for unsigned numbers. For more possibilities see the [format character table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters), and see the [byte order, size, and alignment table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) for options when the output is more than a single byte.

```
import struct
s = struct.pack('<i', 5) # b'\x05\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. str(0x04).encode() gives me '4'. I expect b'\x04'.

Comment: @Tolli then you misunderstood the question. The goal was to produce a byte string that represents the numeric value, not the character. I think you're looking for `chr(n)`.

Comment: Ok. From the example in the question, it looks like you are right. Reading just the question, it's not coat exactly what is being asked. I actually don't want `chr(n)`, because my number may be greater than 255. The struct.pack answer below is what I wanted.

Comment: The problem is that google searching sends you here when you are solving int to bytes, hence why I answered this question (I was trying to do what Tolli was doing). IMO These answers can easily co-exist here. Apparently [all answers were downvoted](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14043886/timeline) which I think was unnecessary - they're all helpful.

Comment: The `.encode()` call here is effectively a no-op in Python 2, since the `str` type is already a bytes (not character text) type. But the answer still works fine.

Comment: Perfect! It is useful for create custom integers, like int8 or int16 and represent then using "bytes" class.

Answer (score 38):

You can use the [struct's pack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack):

```
In [11]: struct.pack(">I", 1)
Out[11]: '\x00\x00\x00\x01'
```

The ">" is the [byte-order (big-endian)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) and the "I" is the [format character](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters). So you can be specific if you want to do something else:

```
In [12]: struct.pack("<H", 1)
Out[12]: '\x01\x00'

In [13]: struct.pack("B", 1)
Out[13]: '\x01'
```

*This works the same on both python 2 and [python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).*

Note: the inverse operation (bytes to int) can be done with [unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack).

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer to a very different question than the one asked here. The number 1 should yield the bytestring b'1', not b'\x01' and not related to any byte order.

Answer (score 16):

I have found the only reliable, portable method to be

```
bytes(bytearray([n]))
```

Just bytes([n]) does not work in python 2.  Taking the scenic route through bytearray seems like the only reasonable solution.

Comment: This works only for integers from 0 to 255.

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer to a very different question than the one asked here.  bytes(bytearray([65])) is b'A', the thing requested here is b'65'.

Answer (score 9):

Converting an **int** to a **byte** in Python **3**:

```
    n = 5    
    bytes( [n] )

>>> b'\x05'
```

;) guess that'll be better than messing around with strings

source: http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binaryseq

Comment: Nadu, I much prefer your answer:
Comparing this answer with the one from @MarkRansom, the values returned are different:
`print(str(8).encode()) #Prints b'8'`
but
`print(bytes([8]))` prints
`b'\x08'`

Comment: @Startec indeed there is a difference: Try type( print(bytes([8])) ) and you get  <class 'NoneType'> while the same on ....encode() give you <class 'bytes'>.  First is a class and later a primitive. Both are functional identical. However in some situations only one of these may be accepted. Not yet encountered that in python. But recently I had struggle in C# with int and Integer. Only the later you can use in generics. Functions demanding 'primitive' int won't accept Integer. Convert int into Integer is 'costly'. So these are like two paths you can go either the primitive or the class one.

Comment: That could cause you a problem if your "int" is greater than 255, because of course "bytes" would expect items smaller than one byte in its initialization list.

Comment: `bytes( [256] )` -> `ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)`. Limited to small integers.

Comment: Depends.  If the expeted value is b'5' this is just plain wrong.  So good code in some cases, but NOT an answer to this question.

Answer (score 8):

In Python 3.x, you can convert an integer value (including large ones, which the other answers don't allow for) into a series of bytes like this:

```
import math

x = 0x1234
number_of_bytes = int(math.ceil(x.bit_length() / 8))

x_bytes = x.to_bytes(number_of_bytes, byteorder='big')

x_int = int.from_bytes(x_bytes, byteorder='big')
x == x_int
```

Answer (score 6):

from int to byte:

```
bytes_string = int_v.to_bytes( lenth, endian )
```

where the lenth is 1/2/3/4...., and endian could be 'big' or 'little'

form bytes to int:

```
data_list = list( bytes );
```

Comment: This does something entirely different.  It converts the a number to bytes representing that number in a raw integer value, to the bytestring (e.g. (65).to_bytes()) is b'A', not b'65' as requested in the question).

Comment: moreover ` list( bytes )` does not produce an `int` but a `list`

Answer (score 1):

When converting from old code from python 2 you often have "%s" % number this can be converted to b"%d" % number  (b"%s" % number does not work) for python 3.
The format b"%d" % number is in addition another clean way to convert int to a binary string.

```
b"%d" % number
```