# Python 3 Converting integers to bytes correctly:

Tags: python, utf-8, byte

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043886/python-2-3-convert-integer-to-bytes-cleanly) make it seem like there are two ways to convert an integer to a `bytes` object in Python 3. They show

`s = str(n).encode()`

and

```
n = 5    
bytes( [n] )
```

Being the same.  However, testing that shows the values returned are different:

```
print(str(8).encode()) 
#Prints b'8'
```

but

```
print(bytes([8])) #prints b'\x08'
```

I know that the first method changes the `int 8` into a string (`utf-8` I believe) which has the hex value of 56, but what does the second one print? Is that just the hex value of 8? (a `utf-8` value of backspace?)

Similarly, are both of these one byte in size? It seems like the second one has two characters == two bytes but I could be wrong there...

Comment: the \x in \x08 is just indicating that the 08 is a hex number. Both results are one byte.

Comment: How do the answers show them being the same? The answers make it very clear that they're doing different things—one returns the ASCII-encoded string representation of the number 8, the other returns the byte 8. These are not at all the same.

Comment: Also, if you want to know how long the second one is, why not ask it: `print(len(bytes([8])))` will give you `1`. It is just the single UTF-8 value of backspace, as you suspected, which is one byte, not two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two examples are *not* equivalent. `str(n).encode()` takes whatever you give it, turns it into its string representation, and then encodes using a character codec like utf8. `bytes([..])` will form a bytestring with the byte values of the array given. The representation `\xFF` is in fact the hexadecimal representation of a *single* byte value.

```
>>> str(8).encode()
b'8'
>>> b'8' == b'\x38'
True
```

Comment: When I do str(8) it just returns 8 as a string, not a byte object. When you say "byte values" do you mean their decimal values?

Comment: My apologies, I omitted the `.encode` by accident. However, you should note that what that `.encode()` does is take the unicode string and transform it to an 8-bit string (i.e. a bytestring) using a character codec; in the end it still represents text. When I say an array of "byte values", I do mean decimals. Specifically integers in the range [0,255]. Any value greater than 255 or less than 0 would give you an error, because it's not a byte!

Answer (score 5):

`b'8'` is a `bytes` object which contains a single byte with value of the character `'8'` which is equal to `56`.

`b'\x08'` is a `bytes` object which contains a single byte with value `8`, which is the same as `0x8`.